# How do you send the response headers in IIS?

Tags: iis

I'm more specifically looking to set the Expires and the Last-Modified headers on static content (images, css, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS Admin, go to the properties of the website.

Click on HTTP Headers then set the content expiration values.

Best way to set it on static content is to just keep all the static content in a 'Content' folder away from dynamic files

Answer (score 0):

This module can help you to operate with request/response HTTP headers: http://www.helicontech.com/ape/doc/mod_headers.htm